# How to keep text aligned to top of textview when changing to landscape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I change the orientation from portrait to landscape I would like the text to re-align itself so it starts from the top, instead of part-way through the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a method to call once the orientation changes, try adding the following there:

```
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))
```

Comment: If I try that I get an error message "extra argument in call"